# CRUD based authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, crud, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Does anyone know of a quick way to add a role CRUD system to rails?

I only want admins to create users and have all currently signed up users listed on a page in my app.

Im trying to figure out a way to assign users to different roles and restrict them for performing certain actions using collection select or a series of checkboxes.

Ive followed a few tutorials but none seem to be working for me :/

Can anyone recommend a solution? I us devise for my authorization it that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try using API Keys if you want to expose this API to many others

Answer (score 2):

You can think about [CanCan](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan). Using it you're able to define roles and restrict access to certain actions or model elements according to the role.

It can be also easily integrated with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) mentioned by Scott Schulthess.

Answer (score 1):

Devise on github has a wiki page showing how to do this

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role